# Drupal to Wordpress - Migrating Comments

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I have a Drupal 6.25 database that I'm trying to migrate to Wordpress (v3.4.1). I'm able to copy the content into Wordpress, but when it comes to comments, I seem to have trouble with converting the `thread` column (in Drupal comments table) to `comment_parent` (in Wordpress wp_comments).

Here's the code that I'm using (taken from a [tutorial](http://blog.room34.com/archives/4530)):

```
INSERT INTO `mywordpress`.wp_comments
(comment_post_ID, comment_date, comment_content, comment_parent, comment_author,
comment_author_email, comment_author_url, comment_approved)
SELECT DISTINCT
    nid, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), comment, thread, name,
    mail, homepage, ((status + 1) % 2)
FROM mydrupal.comments;
```

The above doesn't work since Wordpress `comment_parent` is a BIGINT type while the Drupal `thread` column is a VARCHAR, with values such as `0a.01.03.00/`,

How can these be transformed into Wordpress compatible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query (I've taken it from this [tutorial](http://fuzzythinking.davidmullens.com/content/moving-from-drupal-7-to-wordpress-3-3/)):

```
UPDATE IGNORE wordpress.wp_term_relationships, wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy
SET wordpress.wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wordpress.wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
```